# How do I Make search of an Item in json Url in addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()

Tags: android, json, search, textwatcher

Currently I have been stuck in the implementation of the search item json  Url logic. I have TextWatcher code but I do not know how to implement to search an item that user input in the EditText.
I want once the user start typing the search will be triggered and search dynamically, and once the user hits on the DONE button on the Keyboard the string in the EditText will be searched automatically
How do I implement this ? Or is there someone with a better idea?
Please provide examples...Thanks in Advance.

Comment: so you are stuck on making a json web request?

Comment: I have Json request code and it is working but the problem is how to parse the string being typed by the user to the Json request code.

Comment: it depends on the request you are using and nobody knows what your request really is

Answer (score 0):

It is good if you can save your json data to local storage using mysqlite or you can also use ArrayList for storing your json data.

1. download all json data on OnCreate() method of activity.
2. store it to ArrayList.
3. Display it to ListView by setting up adapter
4. When textchanged in EditText create new ArrayList and set again adapter with upgraded list of data.

hope this may help you.